# Java Apache Beam Testing pipeline replaces test data with null values

Tags: java, testing, apache-beam

I have created a test pipeline like this:

```
        Pipeline pipeline;
        PipelineOptions pipelineOptions = TestPipeline.testingPipelineOptions();
        pipeline = Pipeline.create(pipelineOptions);

        FlattenLight flattenLight = new FlattenLight();
        DataflowMessage dataflowMessage = getTestDataflowMessage();
        
        PCollection<TableRow> flatttened = pipeline
                .apply("Create Input", Create.of(dataflowMessage))
                .apply(ParDo.of(flattenLight));
```

I want tot test the FlattenLight class, it is a DoFn child with a `processElement(ProcessContext c)` method.

The problem is that the test data generated with `getTestDataflowMessage()` does not goes through the pipeline. The FlattenLight object receives an Object with null values as fields.

The getTestDataflowMessage() creates fields as expected. You can see a lot of different test values are present:

[debugger step at test data creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYnI5.png)

But the FlattenLight class receives an Object that is mostly empty:

[debugger step entering the FlattenLight object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NypXI.png)

As you can see there is not step between the data creation and the FlattenLight processing. Why does this happens? How to fix it?

Comment: What Coder are you using for DataflowMessage?

Comment: @robertwb I am using none. Is it necessary?

Comment: My guess is that DataflowMessage is somehow not getting serialized correctly. What is its definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The solution was to add `implements Serializable` to all  models within the model hierarchy. Take a closer look at your DataflowMessage, maybe you missed it somewhere.

Comment: This will cause the `SerializableCoder` to be used. That is a great start. Then you may want a more efficient encoding and you can apply the `@DefaultCoder` annotation to the `DataflowMessage` class to encode it as e.g. Avro or Beam Row format.